# How to lubricate a bicycle cable

Tags: maintenance, cable

so I'm very new to all this, so I don't know a lot. My mountain bike will no longer shift gears, I've been told this is because my cables need lubricated, but I have no idea how to do this, so, how would I do that with a spray lubricant?

And please keep in mind, I don't really know anything about bikes.

Comment: I read that post before I posted, unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: That link is How.  The accepted answer: Popping the quick releases on brakes or frame attachments on gear cables, then dribbling chain lube along the inner so it runs down into the outer works well on cables that are already installed and doesn't require re-adjusting anything afterwards   ...  If there is a specific step that is confusing the post detailed question with picture.

Comment: I reread the post, and I just didn't understand some things the first time, I think I've got it now though.

Answer (score 3):

It is always strongly recommended (by the manufacturers, I read it on Shimano's instruction sheet) **not** to lubricate a new cable when you're installing it. The reason is that both cable and housing are teflon-coated at the factory and lubrication could destroy that. When a cable loses the ability to move freely it is best replaced together with the housing.

Comment: If I were trying to install a new cable, I would have asked how to do that, I'm trying to lubricate an older one because my gears won't shift.

Comment: Why post an answer to a duplicate question?